# How to do function call inside execute method?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am doing retrieve user details from active directory into SharePoint.

I want to call these 2 following functions in my **public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)** method but i have tried a lot still cant figure it out the way.

```
public static IList<LdapUser> GetUsersFromActiveDirectory(string connectionString)
    {
        some codes here
    }



public void SaveActiveDirectoryUsersToSharePointList(IList<LdapUser> ldapUsers)
    {
        some codes here
    }
```

I want to do the function call so that it can display the user details from active directory to SharePoint List [LDAPUsers].

The following code is incorrect.
It showed me the SPListItem has some invalid arguments.
I understand that the problems of invalid arguments occurred, but i cant figure it out any other way to do the function call. Or i shouldn't do it inside SPListItem?

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId) 
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        SPList taskList = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["LDAPUsers"];
        SPListItem newTask = taskList.Items.Add(SaveActiveDirectoryUsersToSharePointList(GetUsersFromActiveDirectory(connectionString)));
        newTask.Update();
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? "It doesn't work" is not a good problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

(Without knowing what you're actually doing in your functions, which doesn't matter here I think) Your code is trying to set an SPListItem object equal to an SPList object, which can't be done. The "SPListItem newTask = " can be dropped and just run the method taskList.Items.Add (and then pass in whatever parameters are needed for that item).

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467435(v=office.14).aspx) MSDN article has the full method for creating an individual list item.

For whatever your custom functions are doing, you may want to

1) Query your data into some sort of list or array (as it appears you do with GetUsersFromActiveDirectory)

2) Access the SP list item collection / SP list (as you did with taskList)

3) Loop through the list/array from step 1, 
 a) Create a new list item 
 b) mapping individual columns of data from the list/array to values for the item (ie newTask["Title"] = TextBox2.Title)
 c) add list item to list collection / list

4) add/commit values to list (ie individually or as a group through .update())